# Using the Facebook Graph API to change a users profile page, based on the user who is logged in via Facebook in-app

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, web-applications

I want to allow users to login to my application (coded using HTML/CSS/JavaScript) via Facebook, and when they navigate to the profile page section of the app, they see their profile picture and account info (in a similar way to Instagram, but instead of photo's they have taken, their friends profile pictures are there and are clickable, which takes you to the friends profile). In addition, is it possible to allow users to create events in app that are created using Facebook, which then sends a push notification to any friends invited?

Comment: Yes everything is possible. Start coding now :D http://developers.facebook.com

Comment: how would i go about doing these things?